# Display inputs to std::ostream

Tags: c++, std, ostream

**Disclaimer**: I am a complete C++ beginner, and if there is a similar answer to this question, please direct me to it, as I may have missed it, not knowing much in the way of theory.

Suppose I have a method which accepts a reference to an `ostream`:

```
printAllObjects(std::ostream& os);
```

I am assuming it makes changes to the `ostream`, so that one can print the list of all of the objects to a file, say. (I might be wrong here)

Is there any way of seeing what it writes to the `ostream`? (via `cout` preferably)?

Comment: Do you control `printAllObjects`, or is it part of a library you don't have control over?

Comment: no, it is part of the library we are given, unfortunately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::cout` *is* an `std::ostream`, so just pass `std::cout` to the function and you'll see what it does:

```
printAllObjects(std::cout);
```

This flexibility is the very purpose of accepting a reference to `std::ostream`!

Other stream types<sup>1</sup> inheriting from the `std::ostream` base include:

- `std::ofstream` (for file output)
- `std::ostringstream` (for string output).

<sub><sup>1</sup> That's not to say that `std::cout` is a type; it's not. It's a special, global instance of `std::ostream`.</sub>

Comment: `std::cout` isn't an object I presume? Well this seems to compile anyway, but a new problem is preventing me from testing it. I will get back to you if it is successful, but in the meantime: Thanks (provisionally)

Comment: @qasimir: It is an object.